# Adding to a Scroll to menu items in css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using wordpress and have about 8 menu items and due to how the theme has been designed, some of the menu items (in mobile view) get hidden by the footer. How can i make the menu items scroll such that I can view the items at the bottom of the list?

Here is how it appears on mobile: [goo.gl/Gr2nNn](http://goo.gl/Gr2nNn)

Comment: [Css Overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this `<ul>` element:

```
<ul id="menu-menu-1" class="top-bar-menu left">
```

A max-height and automatic overflow, for example:

```
max-height: 250px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this  element:

```
<ul id="menu-menu-1" class="top-bar-menu left">
```

A max-height and automatic overflow, for example:

```
max-height: 250px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: Why have you just reposted my answer?